# Custom Plugin to Pre-package SpringSecurity Configurations

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I'm attempting to package the spring-security-ldap and spring-security-core in a single plugin that supplies company standard domain-classes, controllers and some utilities. In addition, I would like to include LDAP configuration settings.

The intent is to create one plugin that all company applications can depend on for rapid development of new applications.

In my BuildConfig.groovy I have the following plugins:

```
compile ":spring-security-ldap:1.0.5"
compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7"
```

Then in my plugin descriptor doWithSpring closure I have dynamic config settings:

```
config.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = true
config.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = true
config.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://<myip>'
config.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'CN=<ldap_user>,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=local'
config.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'secret'
config.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base //etc...
```

Now I also have a `loadBefore` in my descriptor to say:

```
def loadBefore = ["springSecurityCore"]
```

This works great on my local machine, it's only when I have the CI software compile does it fail.

> build 11-Oct-2013
>   09:26:30  C:\Users\me.grails\2.1.1\projects\MyApp\plugins\spring-security-ldap-1.0.5\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\ldap\DatabaseOnlyLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:22:
>   error: package org.springframework.ldap.core does not exist
>   build 11-Oct-2013 09:26:30    import
>   org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations;

Is there any way to preset configuration information prior to the SpringSecurity plugins grab hold with their defaults?

Is there any way to "reload" the plugin configurations after I've changed them?

**EDIT**
Example of plugin is now on [Github](https://github.com/jdgiotta/example-company-security-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a plugin that does the exactly same thing. I use the [Platform Core](http://grails.org/plugin/platform-core) to configure my defaults, declaring the [doWithConfig](http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/ref/Plugin%20Conventions/doWithConfig.html):

```
def doWithConfig = { config -> 
  application {
    //Spring Security LDAP
    grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.useRememberMe = false
    if(grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.active) {
      grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider'] // specify this when you want to skip attempting to load from db and only use LDAP
    }
  }         
}
```

I also setup my plugin to load **after**, because I override some Spring Beans:

```
def loadAfter = ['springSecurityCore','springSecurityLdap']
```

Comment: I think `doWithConfig` was removed in 2.1.1. But your suggest may work with `doWithSpring`

Comment: @JohnGiotta doWithConfig is from the plugin Platform Core, did you checked my links?

Comment: hmm Can you share both application and plugin BuildConfig?

Comment: I threw up an example project on [github](https://github.com/jdgiotta/example-company-security-plugin)

Comment: I downloaded your plugin, used grails package-plugin & grails maven-install, and declared it as dependency of a fresh application. It compiled with success. It's something more that you've done?

Comment: That's the crazy part. It only throws errors during compile while in my build server. Not while in local development.

Comment: That's odd. Have you tried to clean your .grails folder? To build a application using Jenkins I use `clean` and  `compile --refresh-dependencies` always.

Comment: Yes. Cleaned, deleted, nuked, all of it. I really think it's the order of compiling my server is using. It attempts to compile LDAP first, so  it's possible "core" doesn't exist yet.

Comment: hmm I think that your server don't find the Spring dependency of ldap. Can you try the 1.0.6 version of the plugin?

Comment: Boom! Got it! The `compile` helped in build, but I also had to first set `grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.active = true` in my plugin descriptor to avoid a `ldapAuthProvider` not found error.